# How do I namespace a model properly in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

L4 was so amazing that everything was working out of the box. I don't understand why did they complicate things by adding these namespaces and there is no explanation in docs of how to use them.

I have a class / model (which does not extend eloquent) called 'General' (General.php). I want to use this inside my controllers, but there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this.

I tried all of these and none seem to work:

```
use App\General;
use \App\General;
use General;
use \General;
```

The Class itself:

```
<?php namespace App;

class General extends Model {


}
```

I feel so sad that I have to switch back to L4 because of this, but I can't find a way to make this work..

Comment: Where's `General.php` located?

Comment: It is located under 'app' folder. I created it using php artisan make:model General --no-migration.

Comment: Then `use App\General;` is correct actually... What error do you get? Class not found?

Comment: Yes, I get the following: FatalErrorException in 12603c403c71969e328fc97e91372b6a line 1:
Class 'General' not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FatalErrorException in 12603c403c71969e328fc97e91372b6a line 1: Class 'General' not found

Looks like you are using the class in your *view* and not the controller. You can do that but you'll have to reference the full class name. For example:

```
{{ App\General::first()->title }}
```

Better practice would be to retrieve the model in the controller and pass it to the view:

```
$general = General::first();
return view('view.name', ['general' => $general]);
```